# Floating list keep order after toggeling in list information

Tags: jquery, html, css

After click to toggle more information the float order is braking. Any ideas how to keep the order as it is?

Also the class `even` can be used if needed, I've tried with float:right; on that one but it didn't work.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/61ab2g6w/

```
<ul class="employee-wrap">
    <li class="employee">1<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div></li>
    <li class="employee even">2<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div></li>
    <li class="employee">3<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div></li>
    <li class="employee even">4<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div></li>
    <li class="employee">5<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div></li>
    <li class="employee even">6<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div></li>
    <li class="employee">7<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div></li>
</ul>

ul, li {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
.employee-wrap {
    width:260px;
}
.employee {
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:orange;
    margin:5px;
}
div {
    display:none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .employee {
        float:none;
    }
}
```

Right order

[image: Right order]

Here "3" is at the wrong place. It should remain below "1"
[image: Wrong order]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this setup:

```
.employee {
    width:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:orange;
    margin:5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/61ab2g6w/1/

Comment: thumbs and points up for emmanuel! thank you! (will accepts as soon as I can)

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS:

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.employee-wrap {
  width: 260px;
}
.employee {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 5px;
  clear: left;
}
.employee.even {
  clear: right;
}
div {
  display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .employee {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.